# Handling multiple vm instances in google compute engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm pretty new to Google Compute Engine, I have 5 types of machines and lets' say 10 instances of each type. I don't wan't to do load balancing on them, so I can't use managed instance groups.
is there any 'smarter' way to copy my files to those VMs and run my software on the VMs remotely and automatically than doing this manually?

Answer (score 1):

Basic startup scripts with gcloud/gsutil to copy from Google Storage and then to the respective VMs.